Using StratifiedGroupKFold in StackingClassifier
How to specify StratifiedGroupKFold within StackingClassifier in sklearn?
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import NuSVC
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier
X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
groups = np.array([i for i in range(10)] * 15)
cv = StratifiedGroupKFold(5, shuffle = False)

estimators = [
    ('rf', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state=42)),
    ('nsv', make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),
                          NuSVC(random_state=42, probability = True)))
]
clf = StackingClassifier(
    estimators=estimators, final_estimator=LogisticRegression(),
    stack_method = 'predict_proba', cv = 5
)
val_score = cross_val_score(
    estimator = clf, 
    X = X, 
    y = y, 
    cv = cv, 
    groups = groups,
    n_jobs = -1
)
val_score

The above works fine. But when I try to replace it with StratifiedGroupKFold in the following 2 ways, neither of them work
I'm not really sure what is the correct method to specify StratifiedGroupKFold groups within StackingClassifier.
Attempt 1
estimators = [
    ('rf', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state=42)),
    ('nsv', make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),
                          NuSVC(random_state=42, probability = True)))
]
clf = StackingClassifier(
    estimators=estimators, final_estimator=LogisticRegression(),
    stack_method = 'predict_proba', cv = StratifiedGroupKFold(5, shuffle=False)
)
val_score = cross_val_score(
    estimator = clf, 
    X = X, 
    y = y, 
    cv = cv, 
    groups = groups,
    n_jobs = -1
)
val_score

This gives
ValueError: cross_val_predict only works for partitions

Attempt 2
estimators = [
    ('rf', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state=42)),
    ('nsv', make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),
                          NuSVC(random_state=42, probability = True)))
]
clf = StackingClassifier(
    estimators=estimators, final_estimator=LogisticRegression(),
    stack_method = 'predict_proba', cv = StratifiedGroupKFold(5, shuffle=False).split(X = X, y = y, groups = groups)
)
val_score = cross_val_score(
    estimator = clf, 
    X = X, 
    y = y, 
    cv = cv, 
    groups = groups,
    n_jobs = -1
)
val_score

This gives
TypeError: cannot pickle 'generator' object

Whats the correct way to use StratifiedGroupKFold within StackingClassifier?

What exactly do you mean by "neither work"? If you get errors, provide those and the tracebacks.

Ideally, provide a [mre], including some toy dataset.

I have edited the question with example code details.
